# Prevent Array From Changing On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to trigger an action on an array value each time a user clicks on it, but for whatever reason even when that array is outside of the function, it still changes the value of it. Would anyone know how to make sure the values of the array outside don't get affected?
Thank you all in advance for your time and help.

jQuery:

```
var nums = new Array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');

$('.nums')on('click', function() {
  var numId = $(this).attr('id');
  var newNums = nums;
  var num = newNums.indexOf('#'+numId);
  newNums.length  = num + 1;

  console.log('#'+numId, nums, newNums, num);
});
```

Comment: Please include your html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `newNums = nums` points to newNums to nums, and doesn't create a copy of the nums array. To create a copy you can use `Array#slice`:

```
var newNums = nums.slice(0);
```

Note that this is a shallow copy. If you're original array contains objects, the new array (after the slice) will contain a reference to the original objects, and changing the "new" objects, will change the originals. In this case, you'll have to make a deep copy, by manually iterating the array, and creating new objects.

Comment: Awesome, that worked like a charm!!! Thank you so much @Ori Dori for your time and help, really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy the array by value using `slice()`, your current assignment gives reference to the `nums` array and whenever a value changes within the function the initial array gets affected:

```
var nums = new Array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');

    $('.nums')on('click', function() {
      var numId = $(this).attr('id');
      var newNums = nums.slice();
      var num = newNums.indexOf('#'+numId);
      newNums.length  = num + 1;

      console.log('#'+numId, nums, newNums, num);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your really quick answer @KAD. As I mentioned to Ori just before, that technique worked perfectly.
Thanks again for your great help (and time of course)